# Where is the authoritative location for new Ubuntu releases?

Tags: 16.04, updates, unattended-upgrades, hash

An AWS droplet running Ubuntu is now reporting itself as Ubuntu 16.04.**5** LTS but I find no reference to this version on ubuntu.com.  The latest version is showing as 16.04.**4**  (http://releases.ubuntu.com )   (note cannot establish a secure connection to releases.ubuntu.com ???)

On 2018-07-20 06:57 unattended upgrades ran and upgraded: base-files

After this upgrade this box started reporting itself as:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1062-aws x86_64)

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Prior to this update this box reported it self as Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

**How can I verify that this update is legit?**

Comment: Note that https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule says 16.04.5 is due on August 2, which means the update will be generally available then (as will the ISOs). That your cloud image shows 16.04.5 is a result of this update in preparation for 16.04.5 GA: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_9.4ubuntu4.7/changelog

Comment: Is there something authoritative?  Note that 16.04.5 is not listed a a future release on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam#Releases.Future 
Any Idea how or why my system could update (unattended upgrades) to an unreleased (future) version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Human error, probably. It is listed on the 16.04 release schedule, as I said.

Comment: please read my comment again. I have given a reason why your system shows 16.04.5.